# NodeJS/ mongoDB assertion error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so I was trying to create a webpage that basically registers you and then sends you a confirmation email. Im facing an Assertion Error. Could like someone tell me where Im going wrong and why the error occurred?

P.S: I will be censoring my private information like email, sendgrid ID & pass
Thank you..

ERROR:

```
    > test@0.0.0 start /Library/nodeJs/test
> node ./bin/www


assert.js:86
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:363:3)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/nodeJs/test/routes/newuser.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/nodeJs/test/app.js:32:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! test@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Library/nodeJs/test/npm-debug.log
```

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var fs=require("fs")
var app = express();
var multer=require("multer");
var crypto=require("crypto");
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/adithya');



app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/newuser', require('./routes/newuser'));


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/registration', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});



//multer




var done=false;

/*Configure the multer.*/





/* app.get('/users',function(req,res){

  mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){

    res.send(users);
  });
});  */

fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function(filename) {
if (~filename.indexOf('js')) require(__dirname + '/models/' + filename)
    console.log("fileread");
}); 


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

index.JS

```
    var express = require('express');
var multer = require("multer");
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'Express' });
});



module.exports = router;
```

user.js (routes)

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var users = require("../models/users")
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("inside get function");
users.find(function(err, users){

    res.send(users);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

user.js (models)

```
    var mongoose= require("mongoose");
var Schema= mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({

    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    status: Number
});

mongoose.model("users",usersSchema);
```

newuser.js

```
    var express= require('express');
var router= express.Router();
var mongoose = require(mongoose);

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log("username : " + req.body.username+", email :  "+ req.body.email+ ", password :  " + req.body.password );

var newUser= users({

    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    status: '0'

});

newUser.save(function(err){
if(err) throw(err)
var Cryptr = require("./cryptr");
    cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');
    var encryptedString = cryptr.encrypt(req.body.username);
  var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')("Username", "Password");
var email     = new sendgrid.Email({
  to:       req.body.email,
  from:     'fromID',
  subject:  'Registration',
  text:    "Pls click on the following link to confirm https:/localhost:3000/confirmation?username="+ encryptedString 
});
sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {


  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(json);
});

res.send("ok");

});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple, syntax error. I typed in `var mongoose = require(mongoose);` instead of `var mongoose = require("mongoose");`My IDE did not point that out.

Thank you